# Does it make any difference if a singleton is used or new object instance?

Tags: java, performance, singleton

I have recently changed job and I am working on a WebSphere Commerce project for a large online retail store, within the code there are various factories for getting instances of various services. However all they are doing is returning a new object every time. e.g.

```
public class DataAccessServiceFactory {

  public static DataAccessService getDataAccessService(){
    return new DataAccessService();
  }
```

This feels like an anti-pattern and it would likely use up resources unnecessarily, instead they should be returning a singleton instance. These services may only have one or 2 private fields of there own however there will be millions of users and therefore millions of unnecessary objects.

So what I would like to know is apart from the factory itself being somewhat pointless as you can create a new object without calling the factory, will this really make any difference in real world use and could there be some benefit to spawning a new service every time you need to use it?

[EDIT]
A bit more detail:
There are various REST services used to query or create entries in the database such as lookup products or add to cart, etc. using these services. The services themselves are stateless.

Comment: How many threads access this getDataAccessService method? Does DataAccessService has state which needs to be shared accross thread? Irrespective What's the use case here?

Answer (score 2):

If DataAccessService has state it shouldn't be a singleton. A million users would all have their own values for each of the attributes of the class, and sharing it would be a synchronization disaster in a multi-user/multi-threaded environment.

The advantage of this class might relate to dependency inversion. If a new mechanism for creating a DataAccessService is ever implemented as a new class entirely, such as SubDataAccessService(extends DataAccessService), all classes that invoke getDataAccessService() would receive the new sub type once the return type is updated in getDataAccessService(). This would prevent the need for refactoring all the code that called

```
 new DataAccessService()
```

to

```
 new SubDataAccessService()
```

Comment: What you say makes sense, but it still does not explain why there isn't just some static instance which is returned when needed.

Answer (score 0):

If DataAccessService isn't stateless, for example it can be inactive and active,  and each user will update it according to logic then it can't be a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Generally Service does not have state, but methods to process data and form a bridge between DAO layer and User/Frontend. If the service does not have class level objects there is not much logic in returning a new instance by using a facotry.

Answer (score 0):

That is really implementation dependent question.

The downside of singleton is that it lives for a long time in the memory since it doesn't get de-allocated like regular objects at the end of their scope.

Also it might use a lot of memory if it caches stuff or has memory leaks.

on the other hand, if it is something that can be reused by many objects, and especially if it takes time to initialize (like DAO object that needs to connect to a database) it can be very beneficial